# jQuery Datatable, Outputting values of textboxes to selected row's columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I currently have a jQuery Datatable, which upon a row being clicked on, the data from that row is outputted to textboxes and select boxes. I'm trying to make it so whatever is entered into the textboxes, will be saved/entered into the selected row upon pressing the saverow button.

Here's my JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o92g9goL/12/)

Javascript:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

(function () {
      var table = document.querySelector('#example');
      var name = document.querySelector('#nameinput');
      var format = document.querySelector('#formatinput');
      var address = document.querySelector('#addressinput');
      var report = document.querySelector('#reportinput');
      var alarm = document.querySelector('#alarminput');



      table.addEventListener('click', onTableClick);

      function onTableClick (e) {
        var tr = e.target.parentElement;

        var data = [];
        for (var td of tr.children) {
          data.push(td.innerHTML);
        }

        name.value = data[0];
        address.value = data[1];
        format.value = data[2];
        report.value = data[3];
        alarm.value = data[4];
        console.log(alarm.value);


      }
        $("#saverow").click(function() {
            var table1 = $('#data-table').DataTable();
            var data = [];
            data[0] = name.value;
            data[4] = alarm.value;
            console.log(name.value);
            console.log(alarm.value);

            table1.draw(true);
        });


})();`
```

With the saverow code, I thought by trying to make the columns equal to the value of the textbox, then redrawing the table would work. The console does have the correct output when you type something new into the textbox then pressing Save. I just cant figure out how to put that back into the selected row.
I'm not wanting to do the inline editing if possible. Trying to keep it in this format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as an answer, but you're not actually doing anything with that `data` variable in the save row click. You take the datatable, do nothing to change it, and then redraw it. So it's not surprising nothing is happening.

See this change to your fiddle to get the rows adding:

https://jsfiddle.net/o92g9goL/14/

Primarily, you need to set the table and datatable into different arrays. Also do it inside the main function. Also you need to actually add this code:

```
datatable.row.add(data).draw(false);
```

As for the editing, you'll need to make sure that you don't just prepopulate it, but make an actual reference to that row, otherwise how will it know to update it?

Comment: How would I go about setting the table and datatable into different arrays? Eventually the table will be populated with data from a database.

Comment: And how would I refer to a row, sorry for the questions, I'm new to coding

Comment: @J.Doe43 Check this link out, especially the examples section: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data() - you could probably find out a lot from just looking through the datatables.net documentation. One thing I noticed that seemed suss was that you were putting the click event on the entire table, when you'd want to put it on the row, as is shown in the examples in that link